# Servlet.doPost() only called after the complete request has been received by the server

Tags: http, servlets, asynchronous, stream, jetty

Why isn't doPost() called immediately?
The client opens an HttpUrlConnection and starts posting data, regularly flushing the output buffer. It uses 10 seconds to complete the post.
I need my servlet to receive the post and start reading from the InputStream as soon as the first bytes are received. However, doPost() is only called after the post has completed.
How can this be fixed?
Does this mean that the web container is buffering the request? How can I stop it from doing that?

Client code:

```
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
        output.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        output.flush();
        System.out.println("partial POST done." + DateTime.now());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    output.close();
```

Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("doPost() " + DateTime.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

How the internet works? Before a request is sent from a browser to the server, the request is broken up into small pieces of data that are called packets. 
Quoting from  http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question525.htm :

> Each packet carries the information that will help it get to its
>   destination -- the sender's IP address, the intended receiver's IP
>   address, something that tells the network how many packets this e-mail
>   message has been broken into and the number of this particular packet.
>   The packets carry the data in the protocols that the Internet uses:
>   Transmission Control Protocol/Internet Protocol (TCP/IP). Each packet
>   contains part of the body of your message. A typical packet contains
>   perhaps 1,000 or 1,500 bytes.
>
> Each packet is then sent off to its destination by the best available
>   route -- a route that might be taken by all the other packets in the
>   message or by none of the other packets in the message. This makes the
>   network more efficient. First, the network can balance the load across
>   various pieces of equipment on a millisecond-by-millisecond basis.
>   Second, if there is a problem with one piece of equipment in the
>   network while a message is being transferred, packets can be routed
>   around the problem, ensuring the delivery of the entire message.

So, for the server to be able to understand what the client is asking for, all the packets must be received and then be assembled. So, what you are asking is practically impossible.

Comment: No, this is possible.
Look at how a browser handles the response from an http GET request for a large jpeg. The image is partially displayed when the first few packets have arrived, and then the image view is continuously updated as more packets arrive.